# where can I find list of builtin objectClasses and attributes for OpenLDAP?

Tags: ldap, openldap

where can I find the list of built-in objectClasses and attributes the OpenLDAP server ships with?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a set of core schema shipped as part of the source tarball, but its been a while since I needed to build it from source.  On an RPM-based package system I usually see them in /etc/openldap/schema or /etc/ldap/schema.

Whether a particular schema file is active or not is governed by the slapd configuration.

Comment: aren't there any hard coded attributes/objects in the OpenLDAP itself?

Comment: Oh, you mean the operational attributes?  I'm not aware of any authoritative list of them, only that you can query existing LDAP entries for the operational attributes currently set.

This might be more enlightening:
http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch3/#operational